# Vue.js/Template: Using .env?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, environment-variables, cloud-foundry

I have a vue.js project based on the webpack template. We deploy to different cloudfoundry environments: Dev, Int and Prod.
For Int and Prod I want to run the app in production mode but with different env variables. I tried to use the following [based on a forum thread](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-implement-shell-environment-variables-in-vuejs-template-webpack/23269):

```
module.exports = {
    NODE_ENV: '"production"',
    SC_AUTH_CLIENT_ID: JSON.stringify(process.env.AUTH_CLIENT_ID),
    API_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_BASE_URL),
};
```

Both `SC_AUTH_CLIENT_ID` and `API_URL` are undefined (although the variables are set in the cf config) - why?

Answer (score 1):

You need a package like [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) you read from the `.env` file. Your shell environment variables will be available in `process.env` but node doesn't by default process `.env` files.

Comment: Somehow that doesn't work... Is it possible that the vue template overwrites anything?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use environment variables set through Cloud Foundry to accomplish what you want.

Ex:

1. `cf push your-app --no-start`
2. `cf set-env your-app NODE_ENV 'development'`
3. `cf start your-app`

Then `process.env` should contain `NODE_ENV` set to `development`.  By default, `NODE_ENV` should be set to `production` as the Node.js buildpack sets that automatically.  You can set other variables in the exact same way.

You do not need a third party library to read them.  Cloud Foundry should expose them as actual environment variables to your process which you can read using the standard method for reading environment variables in your language of choice (eg. `process.env` in Node.js).

Alternatively, you can set environment variables in a CF cli `manifest.yml` file.  If you have a lot to set this can be more convenient as it lets you set them all at once and you don't need to push/start separately, like in the example above.  Details on that [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#env-block).

Hope that helps!